# JPA/ Hibernate function in multiselect NPE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Using a function in a multiselect (or select(construct(...)) results in a NullPointerException (Hibernate 4+) with the following code:

```
criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.construct(OrderCriteria.class,
       order.get(Order_.id),
        criteriaBuilder.function("array_to_string", String.class,
                criteriaBuilder.function("array_agg", String.class, employee.<String>get(Employee_.firstName)), criteriaBuilder.literal(",")),
    ));
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getConstructor(ReflectHelper.java:354)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:185)
```

I have traced the exception back to Hibernate ConstructionNode::resolveConstructorArgumentTypes.

It appears that getDataType() does not exist on MethodeNode (criteriaBuilder.function creates a MethodNode) resulting in a NPE:

```
private Type[] resolveConstructorArgumentTypes() throws SemanticException {
    SelectExpression[] argumentExpressions = collectSelectExpressions();
    if ( argumentExpressions == null ) {
        // return an empty Type array
        return new Type[] {};
    }

    Type[] types = new Type[argumentExpressions.length];
    for ( int x = 0; x < argumentExpressions.length; x++ ) {
        types[x] = argumentExpressions[x].getDataType(); --> [types[x] == null with MethodNode] 
    }
    return types;
}
```

Is there something wrong with the way the select is constructed?

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours it became clear the using an non-registered function cannot be used in this way, resulting in this very unclear exception.

Solution:

```
public class ExtendedPostgreSQL9Dialect extends PostgreSQL9Dialect{

    public ExtendedPostgreSQL9Dialect() {
        super();

        registerFunction("array_agg", new StandardSQLFunction("array_agg", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
    }
}
```